# Getting file inside PCL project always returning null

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library

I am trying to get file which is added in PCL project usin PCLStorgae as below:

```cs
IFile file = await PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.GetFileFromPathAsync("ProjectName.Data.AuthRequest.json");
```

Above is always returning null. BuildAction is set to Embedded Resource. It is possible to get file inside PCL, but what am I doing wrong here.

**Update**

Following code working fine without using PCLStorage:

```cs
var assem = typeof(Class).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

Stream stream = assem.GetManifestResourceStream(string.Format("ProjectName.CustomFolder.FileName"));

using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{
    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Not sure why its returning null with PCLStorage.

Comment: I believe James answered your question on the forum here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80313/unable-to-load-file-using-pcl-storage-in-pcl-project

Answer (score 1):

[PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) is an abstraction over the file system differences of the various native platforms (iOS, Android, Windows etc).

Maybe you found the name of the library misleading? The "PCL" in "PCLStorage" means, it allows you to access the platform specific file systems from within your shared code (PCL). It's *not* about accessing files that are embedded into a PCL as a resource.

As you already figured out correctly, `GetManifestResourceStream()` is the correct way to go for embedded resources.